Pandas read_html: keep cell content format as html
I have a Word document with multiple tables. I'm converting it to html format and read it with pandas:
tables = pd.read_html('report.htm')

But the text in cells has subscripts, superscripts and special characters, so, for example, 5×10-5 becomes 5?10-5, while in html format it is 5&times;10<sup>-5</sup>. Is there the way to read cell contents as raw html with pandas or by using a different approach?

Have you tried specifying encoding parameter to read_html?

@ParmanM.Alizadeh Yes, but it does not affect html tags and special characters.

maybe it would be better to convert the Word document into Excel and use the read_excel function

I suggest, create a PDF and than use camelot-py.

@Paul-ET Thanks, I've tried this library, but for some reason it reads only the first table, also it does not differ between sub- and superscript, it looks at the font size, not the position of a character.
